# Sql Query create date range with single date column

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a table containing a single date column say special date (stored as yyyymmdd )

How do i create a date range among the small subset of rows?

Example table contains a date column with following values 01-jan-2010, 01-feb-2010, 01-mar-2010

I need

```
01-jan-2010 - 01-feb-2010
01-feb-2010 - 01-mar-2010
```

....
....

Please help.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you want. Are you saying that have three dates in your example table, and you want a select statement that returns four, with '20100201' repeated once?

Comment: I think the idea is that the output displays the date-range for a special whereby the end-date is the start-date of the next special. You should consider having two columns start-date, end-date as it will make life so much simpler and be far more extensible... what happens if you have two items on special at once??

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
        DateVal DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO @Table SELECT '01 Jan 2010'
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT '01 Feb 2010'
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT '01 Mar 2010'

;WITH DateVals AS (
    SELECT  *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY DateVal) RowID
    FROM    @Table
)
SELECT  s.DateVal StartDate,
        e.DateVal EndDate
FROM    DateVals s INNER JOIN
        DateVals e ON   s.RowID + 1 = e.RowID
```

Output

```
StartDate                  EndDate
2010-01-01 00:00:00.000  2010-02-01 00:00:00.000
2010-02-01 00:00:00.000  2010-03-01 00:00:00.000
```

You can avoid the CTE by using

```
SELECT  s.DateVal StartDate,
        MIN(e.DateVal) EndDate
FROM    @Table s LEFT JOIN
        @Table e    ON  s.DateVal < e.DateVal
GROUP BY    s.DateVal
HAVING  MIN(e.DateVal) IS NOT NULL
```

But I do not see why you wish to do so.

Comment: Is there any way i can avoid CTE?

Comment: CTE aren't bad? May be sorry for a beginner question